# Difference B/w Collapse and Panel Collapse [Bootstrap]

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, web

I have a little confusion in understanding the difference b/w collapse and panel collapse as they both serve almost same purpose then why we would have to use panel-collapse too when dealing with panels in Bootstrap.

Comment: collapse is just collapsible div, and panel collapse itself indicates collapsible panel. first you need to see Panel

Answer (score 0):

There is no big difference between collapse and panel collapse. Collapse can be used to collapse any div, where as panel collapse is used only with respect to the panels in bootstrap. You can even just use the collapse class to collapse a panel without using panel-collapse.